# JSON in python discord.py

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I'm learning to code discord bots and I'm trying to add a 'money' function that will add 'money' to the user 'account' every time he sends a message.
Here's my problem, the json file writes 'id' : 0 but the python file write id : 0

```
from discord.ext import commands
import json

with open('money.json', 'r') as infile:
    argent = json.load(money)
    print(money)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot:
        id = message.author.id
        if id not in money:
            argent[id] = 0.00
        argent[id] += 5.00
        print(money)
        with open('money.json', 'w+') as outfile:
            json.dump(argent, outfile)
```

Here's my problem, when python load the JSON file, it creates python dict('id' : value) but when python write in the dict, it writes dict(id : value)

dict loaded from JSON:

```
{'299561981311057920': 5.0}
```

Same dict after the program wrote on it :

```
{'299561981311057920': 5.0, 299561981311057920: 5.0}
```

I would like it to write:

```
{'299561981311057920': 10.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your id to a string before pulling it from your dict

`id = str(message.author.id)`